# How do i compute the number of overlapping frames an given audio file has?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given an audio signal has to be framed like this

[image]

The only thing given the frame length (s), overlap length(s), sample rate(hz), and the length of the audio(s).

How do i compute the number of frames an audio would have given these parameter:

example:

frame length = 25 ms

overlap length = 10 ms

sample rate = 16000 hz

audio lenght = 2s

how many frames would there be in this audio file?

Information audio signal:

```
SA2.wav:

 File Size: 70.0k     Bit Rate: 260k
  Encoding: Signed PCM    
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit   
Samplerate: 16000Hz      
Replaygain: off         
  Duration: 00:00:02.16  

In:100%  00:00:02.16 [00:00:00.00] Out:95.1k [      |      ]        Clip:0    
Done.
```

**Edit**

The formula that seem to fit this seem to be:

```
audio_length*sample_frequency = frame_length*sample_frequency + (n-1)*overlap*sample_frequency
```

Tested:
with audio 4.761625 seconds => 76186 samples

```
In[18]:= Solve[76186 == 400 + (n - 1)*160, n] // N


Out[18]= {{n -> 474.663}} %extracted 474
```

Not sure why though ?

Comment: You can divide out sample frequency from your equation.  Then where you have overlap I have (frame step-overlap).  If you look at your drawing I think (frame step-overlap) makes sense.  If the overlap were equal to the frame step I would have all the frames on top of each other, while your length would be the number of frames times the frame step.  I don't see where 76186 comes from.  It is close to $70 \cdot 1024$, but that is $71680$ and reading the duration from the file size doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Its a different audio file i've tested for.. its longer than the other one. hence more sample.

Comment: I would guess you have misunderstood the information provided and what you are calling the overlap is in fact the non-overlapped part of the frame.  That would make the overlap $15$ and the non-overlap $10$. Then we would both agree that each frame adds $10$ msec to the duration and the calculation would make sense.

Comment: I didn't make the figure.  Its found from a google search.  http://kom.aau.dk/group/04gr742/pdf/framing_worksheet.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The end of frame 1 is at the frame length.  The end of frame 2 is a twice the frame length minus the overlap.  Each successive frame adds the frame length minus the overlap.  The total time for $n$ frames is then $n$ times the frame length minus $n-1$ times the overlap.  In your example, $2000=25n-10(n-1)$ where our units are milliseconds.  This gives $1990=15n, n=\frac {398}3 \approx 133$

Comment: I am not sure... I tried with an audio file, and I got 477 frames from 2.16 second long audio file.. with your method it would have been 143 frames.

Comment: It is pretty simple, so I think my calculation matches the model you showed.  Maybe the model is not correct.  Essentially (iignoring the startup) each frame contributes what you called frame step, which is just the frame length minus the overlap.  You would have a frame step of about 5 msec.

Comment: @user25778 That is roughly a payload of 4.5ms per frame. Is your signal mono? Is it really fixed frame length PCM?

Comment: The signal is mono, I added information about the audio file.

Comment: @RossMillikan I seem to have found the solution, but not sure why it fits?

Answer (score 0):

$k$ frames cover the time
$$
t(k) = t_f + (k-1) (t_f - t_o)
$$
The minimal coverage would be a $k$ with
$$
t(k-1) < t \le t(k)
$$
In your case
$$
2000 > 25 + (k-2) (25 - 10) =  25 + 15 (k-2) = 15 k - 5 \iff \\
k < 2005 / 15 = 133.6\dotsb
$$
So we have $k= 133$.

Comment: That provides a similar result to the other answer..